# Is it possible to change meaning of ANSI escape codes for colors?

Tags: windows-7, mingw, git-bash, escape-sequences

I'm using a Git Bash (1.8.3) under Windows 7.

Many of the command line tools come with the text highlighting using ANSI escape codes. However I've noticed the exact interpretation of the colors differs between the platforms.

For instance, on Windows, the red color in reality is a very dark red, which is almost unreadable on a black background. "Real" red (#FF0000) can be achieved by using the escape code for "bold red".

Regarding the Git itself, I can change the highlighting in gitconfig, but there are simply many command line tools with hardcoded ANSI escape codes for dark red.

Is it possible to override the meaning of those codes, so for instance I can change "red" to be "bold red" (or any other color) for all programs run in the terminal?

Or maybe is there some tool that gets data from pipe and changes the colors on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the default Windows console, open the system menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) and select "Properties" (or "Defaults" for all console windows). You will find the color palette customization there.

[image: freehand circle]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. In the settings you mention, I can change default colors for console, so for instance, instead of being white-text-on-black, I can have yellow-on-blue. But I want instead to change let's say here: https://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20110413-n3hcc29tfgge4h8p9i5gi2e1b8.png to have cyan instead of red (but for all the possible command line applications).

Comment: @jakub.g: [The *same* tab has settings for changing all color values.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7gP5l.png)

Comment: Ah, I haven't realized that this is effectively editing the pallette for the other colors too! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some console replacements support changing the colors along with other features missing with the one that comes with Windows.

One example [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/p/console/wiki/Home/). Note that behind it is still the same cmd.exe as the normal console window or another command processor if desired. An example of the settings dialog where Yellow has been made to show as blue.

[image]

To setup Git Bash to use it: [Git Bash & Console2, Finally!](http://johngilliland.wordpress.com/2012/12/22/git-bash-console2-finally/) which shows a settings dialog with what worked for them.

[image]

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer! I'll check it out soon!